# Изменить запрос под условие

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

мне нужно, чтобы если kr = null, то убираем из условия "dat = 0323". Как бы можно было это реализовать?

```
select * ,
    case when kr is null then 'НЕ ПОДАН'
        else substring(kr,9,2)+'.'+substring(kr,6,2)+'.'+substring(kr,1,4)
    end as kroy,
    case when substring ([Наименование],1,1) ='*'
        then NULL
        else dz
    end as data_zapuska,
from (
    select
        mex_cex.dbo.model.id_model,
        mex_cex.dbo.model.kod_modeli as 'km',
        mex_cex.dbo.model.kod_modeli as 'Код модели',
        case when mex_cex.dbo.model.kod_modeli in (
                select distinct Model_ID
                from [NSI].[dbo].[SprInfoModel]
                where Date_Starting between '01.03.2023' and '31.03.2023'
            )
            then nsi.dbo.SprMod.NP
            else '* ' + nsi.dbo.SprMod.NP
        end as 'Наименование',
        mex_cex.dbo.model.familiya as 'Технолог',
        mex_cex.dbo.model.status as 'Статус',
        mex_cex.dbo.model.status2 as 'Статус2',
        DATENAME(month, mex_cex.dbo.model.period) AS 'Период ',
        data_zapuska as dz,
        rez_priemki,
        data_priemki,
        prim_ipk,
        isnull(
            isnull(
                (select top 1 smu.KU
                from NSI.dbo.SprModUh smu
                where smu.MOD = mex_cex.dbo.model.kod_modeli and smu.KU is not null
                order by dat desc),
                (SELECT top 1 [ku] FROM [1201].[dbo].[Plane_PM] where km = mex_cex.dbo.model.kod_modeli and ku is not null)
            ),
            (SELECT top 1 [ku] FROM [1201].[dbo].[Plane] where km = mex_cex.dbo.model.kod_modeli and ku is not null)
        ) as uch,
        cast(cast((
            SELECT min([DT1])
            FROM [CRB].[dbo].[M070102]
            WHERE m = mex_cex.dbo.model.kod_modeli and dat = 0323
        ) as date) as varchar) as kr
    from mex_cex.dbo.model
    left join nsi.dbo.SprMod on mex_cex.dbo.model.kod_modeli = nsi.dbo.SprMod.M
    where mex_cex.dbo.model.period = '01.03.2023'
) a
order by case when substring(a.[Наименование], 1, 1) = '*'
                then '11'
                else '0'
         end,
         uch,
         cast(rtrim(ltrim(a.[Код модели])) as int)
```

Comment: *если kr = null, то убираем из условия "dat = 0323"* `WHERE .. AND (dat = 0323 OR kr IS NULL) ..`

Comment: @Akina Сообщение 207, уровень 16, состояние 1, строка 16
Недопустимое имя столбца "kr".

Comment: Значит, у них несовпадающая область видимости, и поставленное тобой условие некорректно.

Comment: @Akina , я предоставил весь код

Comment: Неотформатированный, с кучей подзапросов вместо CTE - одним словом, в принципе нечитаемый. Мне в этом многоэтажном безобразии разбираться тупо лень. И, думаю, желающего вообще не найдётся. PS. И тег [mysql] следует убрать - он тут вообще не при чём.

Comment: отформатировал запрос. Этот запрос изначально таким сделали, мне необходимо только изменить, поэтому без CTE

Comment: Ну теперь хорошо видно, что поставленное условие есть лютый бред. Ибо условие `dat = 0323` используется для вычисления значения `kr`. Решение - в подзапросе использовать не отбор по `dat`, а отбор по всему массиву с группировкой по `dat` и сортировкой по `dat = 0323` и `TOP 1`.

Comment: @Akina вы имеете ввиду так:
```cast(cast((
        SELECT TOP 1 CAST([DT1] AS DATE)
        FROM [CRB].[dbo].[M070102]
        WHERE m = mex_cex.dbo.model.kod_modeli 
        AND dat = 0323
        ORDER BY CAST([DT1] AS DATE) ASC
    ) as date) as varchar) as kr```

Comment: Как-то так: ```cast(cast((SELECT TOP 1 MIN([dt1]) FROM [crb].[dbo].[m070102] WHERE m = mex_cex.dbo.model.kod_modeli GROUP BY dat ORDER BY CASE WHEN dat = 0323 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, 1) as date) as varchar) as kr```.